# Crystal Report show slow in server side

Tags: .net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I created a blank report.rpt and give some label using VB.NET 2012, and it show normally in my local pc, then i try to publish to server and it show normally also.

After that i tried to modify some design report from portrait to landscape and publish it again to server, unfortunately is **show very slow in server**, than in my local pc. is there any issue in crystal decision report GAC version 13.0.2000 ? and how i solve this issue ?

```
my server spec and application that i already installed:

- windows server 2008 R2 64 bit
- sap crystal report runtime engine for .net framework 4 version 13.0.0.99
```

Thank you for your support and advice.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to **download the latest support pack from SAP Crystal report** in this link :

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

And installed in server with this version 13.0.10.1385 and my issue is gone.
So try this, if you have the same issue.